# Running mamp pro in cgi mode - how to enable html to run as php

Tags: php, mamp, mamp-pro

I've tried everything I can think of to run .html files as php in CGI mode on MAMP Pro and nothing seems to work. Currently, I'm trying this but apache fails to start -

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .html
FCGIWrapper /Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php5.6.25.fcgi .html
```

I've also tried a whole bunch of different AddHandler options.

Has anyone successfully been able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
AddHandler php-fastcgi .html
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how or why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.